# Vim misses a few files when opening multiple files

Tags: vim-windows, split, multiple-files

I use `vim -o a*` to open 25 files (filenames starting with 'a') together and search & replace (`:windo %s/old/new/gcI`) some common word in these files. Later I found that not all of them have been modified and it seems to be due to that `vim -o` opens only 23 of them. However, `vim -O a*` can open all 25 files.

So is there any safe way to make sure every file is opened (and thus modified), hopefully not by counting windows by eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a slightly different take, vim also preserves the files given it on the command-line in an argument list (colloquially: `:args`). When you use `:next`/`:prev`, you traverse that list. You can change, add to, and operate further on that list with many functions/commands (see the help).

Of particular note is `:argdo` which, alongside its cousins `:bufdo`, `:windo`, `:tabdo`, `:cdo`, and `:ldo`, traverses the list and runs a command.

So in your case, I would do

```
$ vim a*
:argdo %substitute/old/new/g
```

Alternately:

```
$ vim a*
:vimgrep /old/ ##
:cdo substitute//new/g
```

Where this version first searches for the word to change in the arglist (`##`) and then applies the change. The advantage here is the quickfix list gives you a preview of all the occurrences about to be changed. If you don’t like it, you can try a different search pattern or use the `:Cfilter` command from a built-in package.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I'm just not aware that `arg` and `buf` are more complete than `win`. When does `arg` differ from `buf`? Thanks.

Comment: The buffer list is all buffers in memory. Files in the argument list may or may not be in memory, but are a separate list. Its initially the command line arguments, but can be changed/refined interactively. It is common to maintain the argument list as a subset of the buffer list that you’re particularly interested in.

Comment: However, after `:argdo edit` all the files in the arguments list should also be in the buffer list

Answer (score 3):

When opening multiple files, Vim will only create as many windows as it can display, and load the rest without displaying them, in what we call `buffers`.

The help states:

```
Summary:
   A buffer is the in-memory text of a file.
   A window is a viewport on a buffer.
   A tab page is a collection of windows.
```

You can display a list of currently open buffers with `:ls`. You could also use [Fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf.vim) and the `:Buffers` command it provides.

You can access any buffer with `:buffer [name or number]`, and navigate with `:bnext` and `:bNext`, or `:bn` and `:bp` (next / previous).

You may want to take a look at [`:h windows`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html), especially the sections covering "buffers".